# checking if data-val-required exist

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

inside js script I'm trying to recognize if data-val-required exist on certain element.

```
var attrExist = $('#myElem').find('[data-val-required]');
    if (attrExist.length > 0){
            // todo
    }
```

but this doesn't work, cause I'm getting always inside console attrExist as Object[].

How can test if data-val-required attr exist?

update:
rendered html looks like

```
<select id="myElem" class="multiselect form-control" name="someName"
         multiple="multiple" data-val-required="This field is required." 
         data-val="true" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: What is the element with `id="myElem"`. Does it contain a child element that contains a `data-val-required` attribute (or does the element itself contain that attribute)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that the `find()` function looks **inside** `#myElem` if there exists a element with a `data-val-required` attribute.

So if you want to check if `#myElem` has the attribute `data-val-required` use:

```
var dataAttr = $('#myElem').data('val-required');
//var dataAttr = $('#myElem').attr('data-val-required'); // alternative
if (typeof dataAttr !== typeof undefined && dataAttr !== false) {
    // attribute is set
}
```

As alternative, you can look if there is any element that has both the id and attribute (by using, id and attribute selector). This solution makes most sense when using classes.

```
if( $('#myElem[data-val-required]').length > 0 ) {
    // element with that attribute exists
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do,

```
if ($('#myElem[data-val-required]').length > 0)
```

Your code will check for the child elements which have `data-val-required` attribute